# Google Chrome displays the page in Dutch language, but i'm want to see in English/Russian

Tags: google-chrome, localization

I've been looking for an answer to this question for a very long time, but I can't figure out what the problem is. In the settings, everything is set correctly, only English and Russian. But in Accept-Language headers substitutes the `nl-NL` string `accept-language: en,nl-NL;q=0.9,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6`, although I have nowhere Dutch is set neither in the system language, etc. In principle, my system is completely in English with English localization

[Google Chrome settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uk9y.png)

[Header accept-language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Don.png)

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when you're accessing the google search via VPN (IP of different region other than yours) or accessing cloud hosted VM (like VM hosted in West Europe, etc.).

We usually open links with https://www.google.com (sometimes it don't work) and make sure at the bottom of the search page that location is out city or atleast our country.

Whenever we search for the first time, it says to change the setting and we switch it back to english and it works smooth after that.

Comment: I have never used a Dutch VPN, my Google search shows my country of residence (and it is not the Netherlands). For example Linkedin shows up in Dutch, Tutanota mail also, some sites in English, some in Dutch